# How to add N ggplot histograms bin by bin

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

My situation is that I am forced to split a large file into chunks due to its size.  I would like to have a histogram of one of the columns across all the files, so I am forced to histogram each chunk and add the resulting histograms together bin by bin. The histograms are saved as a list as follows:

```
for (i in 1:8) {
    dataset <- read.csv(capture.output(cat("split1/", filelist[i], sep = "")))
    dataset.hist[[i]] <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Value)) 
    + geom_histogram(breaks = seq(1, 200, by=1), aes(fill = ..count..))
}
```

I am attempting to add them like so:

```
testHist <- dataset.hist[[1]] + dataset.hist[[2]]
```

and the following error message results:

```
Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"
```

I looked around on google as well as the ggplot and geom_histogram help pages and gained no new insights. Can anyone out there suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: Would compiling the specific values into one vector work?  `histcol<-rbind(t1.Value,t2.value,...)` sort of thing?

Comment: The data frames associated with each file are too large to load them into memory all at once, so I am inclined to say no.  But possibly I could do this solely for the column of interest, although that might be pusing it too.  I will try it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to compute the value in adaptive way then plot a single histogram. You can use `hist`(you can also use `tapply` here) for example to compute occurrence "Value" in each file then aggregate the result in a single data.frame.

```
## get all files in directory split1
res <- sapply(list.files("split1",full.names=TRUE), 
             function(x){
              dat <- read.csv(x)
              ## EDIT :remove data outside the range
              dat <- dat[dat$Value <=200,]
              counts <- hist(dat$Value,breaks=seq(200),plot=FALSE)
              rm(dat)
              }
     )

## aggregate all counts and create a single data.frame
dat <- data.frame(Value=rowSums(res),
                breaks = seq(200))

## plot the histogram
ggplot(dat) + 
    geom_bar(aes(x=breaks,y=Value),stat='identity')
```

Comment: This seems like what I want to do, although I am getting errors now due to the fact that some of the data points are outside of the range specified by breaks=seq(200).  I don't actually care about these points which is annoying.  I am trying to subset the data to avoid this but I am still new to R so this kind of thing takes me a while to work through :).  Thanks for the response though, will accept officially once I have confirmed that it works.

Comment: @Sledge glad that it works for you. hard to be sure without data. I edit my post to remove data outside the range (0,200) here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this should be a separate answer or a comment on agstudy's post.

@agstudy:  I am posting a small change that I had to make in the event that anyone else out there attempts to do summations of histograms in this way.  I ran into problems caused by returning the histogram to res as an object that complicated the structure of res.  To avoid this I change the code in the sapply statement to return the $counts field from the hist object.  This allows the aggregation that follows to run smoothly since the data structure res only contains the numeric $counts object.  Just FYI.  Thanks again everyone for the help.

```
res <- sapply(list.files("split1/", pattern = "*.csv",  full.names=TRUE), 
          function(x){
            dat <- read.csv(x)
            dat.clean <- dat$Value[which(dat$Value > 0 & dat$Value< 200)]
            dat.counts <- hist(dat.clean, breaks = seq(0, 200, by = 1), plot = FALSE)
            rm(dat, dat.clean)
            # return the $counts field from hist to avoid complicating the list res
            dat.counts$counts
          })

## aggregate all counts and create a single data.frame
dat <- data.frame(Value= rowSums(res),
              breaks = seq(200))

## plot the histogram
ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=breaks,y=Value),stat='identity')
```